# Seekto in videoview is not exact

Tags: android, android-videoview

I use videoview and when I pause app I save currentposition of video and onResume I seekto position that saved and I start video. It delay backward about 2 seconds.

How to seekto is exact

```
public void onResume(){
    videoView.seekTo(currentPosition);
    videoView.start();
}

public void onPause(){
    currentPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
    videoView.pause();
}
```